# Max Recording Length for a call

Tags: rest, twilio, phone-call, maxlength

Wanted to know whats the max length of recording twilio allows for a call, in the TwiML it is specified as 1hr, How about REST API?

Being done a long duration call, how much time does twilio take to prepare the mp3/wav file for this call?

Please share some insights about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

The maximum length Twilio allows for a recording is 4 hours, as that is the maximum length we allow for a call.  This is true when using either the TwiML [`<Record>`](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) verb, or setting the [record](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) attribute to true in the REST API.

If you use the TwiML verb, you can set a URL in the [action parameter](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action) and Twilio will request that URL with the recording completed.  In that request we will pass you a [RecordingURL parameter](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action-parameters) that points to the recording, however its important to know that it might take some time for us to move the file to that location, so you might have to poll that url a few times.

If you set the record parameter using the REST API, we pass the RecordingUrl in the calls [StatusCallback parameter](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter).  Same caveat as above applies.  There may be a delay between when you get the RecordingUrl and when the file is actually there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is the kind of response i must expect when i poll the url and the file isn't there? 404??

Comment: I assume that the request is sent to the StatusCallback whenever any call exceeds the 4hr limit.. Does the call get disconnected in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, you will get a 404 if the file is not yet there.  And yes, at 4 hours, Twilio will automatically disconnect he call and you should get a StatusCallback request.